# How to create REST API for sharing a post or message in Spring Boot for mobile application?

Tags: spring-boot, flutter, spring-restcontroller

I am working for a mobile application (flutter) and using Spring Boot as a backend for creating REST API. There is functionality of share post to different media like SMS / WhatsApp etc. If any user wants to share particular post or SMS to any other using different media then how to do it.
So I am unknown to it. Please suggest me some solutions to achieve. I am attaching screenshot for reference.

[image: Screenshot for share post]

Comment: backend actually doesn't matter if you want to implement api calls then use package like `http`, `dio`,`retrofit` or `chopper` and if you want implement a share functionality then there is a package for that `share_plus` search them on pub.dev

Comment: You will usually use mobile share for that and if you really want to do that you should implement fire-and-forget call with pub-sub pattern to share, using blocking apis for this is not a good idea.

Comment: @silentsudo Do you have any references for fire-and-forget call with pub-sub pattern to share thing? It would be easier for me to understand it more clearly.